Как добавить кнопку delete в li
Как добавить работающую кнопку delete?


const button = document.querySelector(".button");
const todoList = document.querySelector("#myUL");
const input = document.querySelector("#input");
const deleteButton = document.querySelector("delButton");

function addTodo() {
  const Newli = document.createElement("li");
  let deleteButton = document.createElement("button");
  deleteButton.classList.add("delButton");
  deleteButton.textContent = "Delete";
  Newli.append(Button);
  if (input.value != "") {
    Newli.textContent = input.value;
    Newli.id = "li";
    todoList.appendChild(Newli);
  } else {
    alert("Введи что нибудь!!!");
  }
}

button.addEventListener("click", addTodo);

todoList.addEventListener("click", function (event) {
  const lielement = event.target;
  lielement.classList.toggle("checked");
});

deleteButton.addEventListener("click", function () {
  const Newli = document.querySelector("#li");
  Newli.remove();
});
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

/* Remove margins and padding from the list */
ul {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

/* Style the list items */
ul li {
  cursor: pointer;
  position: relative;
  padding: 12px 8px 12px 40px;
  background: #eee;
  font-size: 18px;
  transition: 0.2s;

  /* make the list items unselectable */
  -webkit-user-select: none;
  -moz-user-select: none;
  -ms-user-select: none;
  user-select: none;
}

/* Set all odd list items to a different color (zebra-stripes) */
ul li:nth-child(odd) {
  background: #f9f9f9;
}

/* Darker background-color on hover */
ul li:hover {
  background: #ddd;
}

/* When clicked on, add a background color and strike out text */
ul li.checked {
  background: #888;
  color: #fff;
  text-decoration: line-through;
}

/* Add a "checked" mark when clicked on */
ul li.checked::before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  border-color: #fff;
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 0 2px 2px 0;
  top: 10px;
  left: 16px;
  transform: rotate(45deg);
  height: 15px;
  width: 7px;
}

/* Style the close button */
.close {
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  top: 0;
  padding: 12px 16px 12px 16px;
}

.close:hover {
  background-color: #f44336;
  color: white;
}

/* Style the header */
.header {
  background-color: #f44336;
  padding: 30px 40px;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
}

/* Clear floats after the header */
.header:after {
  content: "";
  display: table;
  clear: both;
}

/* Style the input */
input {
  margin: 0;
  border: none;
  border-radius: 0;
  width: 75%;
  padding: 10px;
  float: left;
  font-size: 16px;
}

/* Style the "Add" button */
.addBtn {
  padding: 10px;
  width: 25%;
  background: #d9d9d9;
  color: #555;
  float: left;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 16px;
  cursor: pointer;
  transition: 0.3s;
  border-radius: 0;
}

.addBtn:hover {
  background-color: #bbb;
}

.li {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
}
    <div id="myDIV" class="header">
      <h2>My To Do List</h2>
      <input type="text" id="input" placeholder="Title..." />
      <button class="button">Add</button>
    </div>
    <ul id="myUL">
      <li id="li">
        Hit the gym
        <button class="delButton">Delete</button>
      </li>
      <li id="li" id="checked">
        Pay bills
        <button class="delButton">Delete</button>
      </li>
      <li id="li">
        Meet George
        <button class="delButton">Delete</button>
      </li>
      <li id="li">
        Buy eggs
        <button class="delButton">Delete</button>
      </li>
      <li id="li">
        Read a book
        <button class="delButton">Delete</button>
      </li>
      <li id="li">
        Organize office
        <button class="delButton">Delete</button>
      </li>
    </ul>




Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Что не так с вашим кодом? Что за кнопка и что она должна делать?

@TaselGames Для начала - const deleteButton = document.querySelector("delButton");, этом коде 2 ошибки. Исправьте и можно будет продолжить, если дальше сами не сделаете.
